# How to debug asyncio coroutines with GDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, gdb, python-asyncio

[There is some extension](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) that allows to use GDB to see detailed info of a Python process, I installed and tried to use it with my hanging web app based on aiohttp. But, whatever request is being processed, I always see only the primary stack trace, with no useful information:

```sh
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 468, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1739, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 539, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 571, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 433, in run_app
    reuse_port=reuse_port))
  File "./my-server/main.py", line 98, in <module>
    web.run_app(app_main, host=host, port=port)
```

This is probably a consequence of separate stack trace created for each coroutine by asyncio.

The goal is to properly debug asyncio apps. So, how can I see execution stack and interrupt/continue coroutines?

Comment: This stack trace indicates that you are obtaining the stack trace _between_ requests, while the event loop is waiting for something to happen.

Comment: @user4815162342 Are you sure? I sent several long requests and started GDB so that requests didn't sent responses before I exited GDB, so I'm sure that they got processed, but in different execution stacks.

Comment: I can't guarantee, as I didn't use pygdb myself, but the stack trace you've shown is pretty clearly one of event loop waiting for io/timeout. The "long request" might have thrown you off because taking long to provide data just suspends the coroutine on the server and the event loop again ends up at its central polling station. Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside one of your coroutines? If you catch a coroutine during execution, I believe you should get a regular stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long digging, I found an alternative solution: simple & amazing **py-spy**! In contrast to gdb, it doesn't require target process to be run with special build of Python, also it has no problem dealing with async functions. Here is a simple use scenario:

```sh
pip install py-spy

# Get stack traces of active threads:
py-spy dump --pid 1

# Watch executing functions in realtime:
py-spy top --pid 1
```

A full description is available here: https://github.com/benfred/py-spy

A notice, important in some environments: just like with gdb, to be used in a Docker container, py-spy requires flag `SYS_PTRACE` to be set.